LGA Socket won't come off
Recently I bought a BGA Station to desolder and solder CPU Sockets. Unfortunately I experience issues with that.
Problem: The CPU Socket won't come off. If I rise the temperature, the plastic around the socket gets soft and ultimately burnt.
How I do it:

I prep the board (Insulation around the socket, taking everything off that can potentially be damaged; cleaning everything around the socket with IPA)
Placing the board, attaching the temperature sensor, apply some flux on the socket (https://www.amazon.de/your-orders/orders?startIndex=10&ref_=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_pagination_1_2)
Placing the Upper heater ~1,5-2cm above the socket.
Preheat from below ~160-180 degrees Celcius and above with ~85 degrees celcius
Once its preheated I start the programm for lead free soldering tin on my ACHI IR6500 rework station -> Picture of the program is included. BGA Station: https://www.ebay.de/itm/333952048605
Waiting till the station is at temperature for desoldering
Despair because the socket wont come off (I try to move/lift it gently with tweezers, wont even move a single bit)
Raising the temperature, doesn't work, ultimately the plastic of the socket is ruined and cant be lifted anymore. I was so desperate, I tried to raise the temperature up to 315 degrees celcius (Upper heat). Lower heat was constantly at ~180 degrees celcius.

Do you have any idea what im doing wrong here? Is it the wrong flux? I experienced issues with it after one successful socket removal when I tried to get the remaining tin off. It was extremely sticky and brown. I was hardly able to remove it with IPA.
Or maybe the board doesn't get enough heat from below?


I'd probably put a temperature probe on the PCB around the socket during preheating and confirm you're getting up to temperature. The board below the socket is full of massive copper planes designed to carry hundreds of amps, so if your preheating isn't working good luck melting that solder from only one side.

Hey there, In step 2 I already said that I attach a temperature sensor... By the way I fixed the problem. Removed the tempered glass above the bottom heater of my bga station. Heat transfer is so much better. I also switched off the fan on my upper heater during desoldering. No problems at all now.
